# jQuery.height() is setting more height than specified in the parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 smaller divs and one large div. I need to adjust the `height` of larger div to be equal to the sum of heights of both divs, plus the `20px` vertical margin between them. Here's what I do:

```
<div id="team-container">
    <div id="block1">Block 1</div>
    <div id="block2">Block 2</div>  
</div>
<div id="team-details"></div>
```

```js
$("#team-container > div").on("click", function(){
    var contentHeight = $("#block1").height() + $("#block2").height() + 20;
    // 20 is for vertical margin
    // if I console log the heights of block divs, it's 263px for certain width, so the total becomes 546, which is correctly logged if I console log contentHeight variable.
    console.log( contentHeight ); // outputs 546
    $("#team-details").height( contentHeight );
    //if I check now by inspecting element, I can see the height has been set to 606px. Why is it so? And on the page also, the larger div is taller than the two smaller divs put together vertically.
});
```

So, the problem is that if I call `.height( 546 );`, it does not set height to 546px but sets it to 606px. But if I set height using css i.e. `.css('height', '546px');`, it works fine and height is set to exactly 546px.

Comment: can you replicate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you provide css for that example

Comment: It's in a bootstrap tabbing component and I do not know exactly how to copy only that to JSFiddle. I have found that if I set the height using `$("#team-details").css( 'height', contentHeight+'px' );`

Comment: You HTML+JS works pretty fine. https://jsfiddle.net/jamiguel77/atg5m6ym/ so I guess you should look into your CSS or something that you didn't tell us.

Comment: Unless you have something else going on (CSS maybe), your code works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/75tp8vfg/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `height` function is actually very smart, and does a lot of calculations behind the scenes, regarding borders, padding margin and so on.

Consider using `$("#team-details").css('height', contentHeight + 'px');`. This is a more direct approach, and if you're doing your own calculation, it might fit you better in this case.

By the way, the `+ 'px'` is actually not needed. From the jQuery documentation:

> When calling .height(value), the value can be either a string (number
>   and unit) or a number. If only a number is provided for the value,
>   **jQuery assumes a pixel unit**

And from the `css` function documentation (http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value):

> When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will **convert it to a
>   string and add px** to the end of that string. If the property requires
>   units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the
>   appropriate units before calling the method.

And one more thing, if you'd like to further understand how the `height` function works, you can check it out here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js in line 333 to line 353. As you can see, it calls the `augmentWidthOrHeight` function, that does some serious calculations and jQuery magic.

Comment: If you're using `.css()` to set the height, you need to provide the unit (px). The main difference between `.height()` and `.css("height")` is that the former returns an unit-less value - useful for calculations.

Comment: yes, exactly. When I use this alongwith 'px' as @MelanciaUK mentioned, it sets the correct height. But why is it so?

Comment: @Mike my comment might clarify it for you.

Comment: @MelanciaUK it clarified the unit thing, but it is not clear as to why when I am calling `.height( 546 );`, it's setting the height to 606px? But when I use 'css('height', '546px')', it works fine.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - I edited my answer and added the `'px'`, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Mike - As I explained in my answer, the `height` functions does a lot of extra calculations before it actually goes to the DOM and changes the style attribute of the element. You can read more about that here: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: The OP code is actually working as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/75tp8vfg/2/. The problem might be somewhere else. Either way would work (`.height()` or `.css("height")`).

Comment: thanks @GiladArtzi